# removing folders with find - strange message

Tags: find

```
mkdir foodir
find . -iname foodir -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

It does the job, but barfs message:

```
find: `./foodir': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can use the ([non standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)) `-delete` option of find to avoid that, instead of `-exec rm`. As for the reason, *Michael Kjörling* gave you the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact sequence of events would go something like

1. create `foodir`
2. launch `find`

   1. find reads the current directory, caches the result and then iterates over it, finding an entry for foodir
   2. find launches the `exec` command for foodir, deleting foodir
   3. find tries to recurse into foodir (it's in find's internal cache), which no longer exists
   4. find displays a warning that it was unable to recurse into foodir
   5. find continues with the next entry (which in this case likely is the end of the list of directory entries, so it exits having done its job to the best of its ability)

So what you are seeing is perfectly explainable, if somewhat unexpected from an outside perspective.

The caching is almost certainly done to improve performance, saving a potentially large number of system calls as well as quite a bit of potential disk I/O for every file. Without a transactional file system, which is common but not guaranteed, there's no guarantee you wouldn't hit issues like this even if find did read the directory once for each entry; and in the case of non-local file systems in particular, even the *order* of the entries might change between checks, so you can't simply keep track of an index either but must keep track of every directory entry you have visited. For a large directory hierarchy, that becomes prohibitive very quickly.

**In general**, this is termed a "[race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)": a precondition for a calculation changing between when the calculation is done and when the resulting value is used.

Looking at the man page for GNU find, there is an option `-ignore_readdir_race` which might help to suppress the warning. However, I don't know how much this does for any other commands executed through find. Depending on your needs, that may be sufficient. You can also suppress any errors and warnings from find by redirecting its standard error to /dev/null (append `2>/dev/null` to the command line), but I do not recommend that since it can hide more serious errors. I also don't know off hand how that would interact with any error output from the invoked command.

Comment: is there any way to get rid of these messages?

Comment: It looks like `-ignore_readdir_race` will do that.

Comment: You can use the `-depth` option to recurse through a directory before handling the directory itself.

Answer (score 1):

`find` stats the target directory as it starts up to get the directory's contents. It then processes the commands you gave it, which, in this instance, change the directory's contents by removing an entry. Therefore, `find`'s idea of what the directory contains, and reality are at odds, and it issues the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to make sense - your command finds foodir then removes it. Ordering of commands is the reason for the message.

Comment: The command finds foodir, then removes it. Agreed. At which point therefore is foodir not found? ("No such file or directory").

Answer (score 0):

Use this command instead

```
find . -iname foodir | xargs rm -Rf
```